# how to run apache commands for Magento in xampp on localhost?

Tags: php, apache, magento, command-line, magento2

Magento 2 installation requires running lot of commands. I'm trying to install magento 2 in localhost on xampp server. And

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-rewrites2.4

requires me to run these commands
1 . " apache2 -v "

2. " apt-get -y install apache2 "
3. " a2enmod rewrite " etc., .

I tired running these commands in composer in root folder of magento 2. But I get error like this - 'apt-get' is not recognized as an internal or an external command , operable program or batch file.

Can some one tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The commands you see are linux commands which you cant run directly for windows. You need something like:http://www.howtogeek.com/141783/how-to-bring-linux-style-apt-get-installations-to-windows-with-chocolatey/

Comment: Why go through the extra pain of kludging Windows to be Linux when you can run Virtualbox, create a Linux LAMP VM and run in a native environment that allows all those Linuxy things natively?

Comment: Thanks @Indrajit  for the comment , Now I know I have to figure out some thing else.